# R shiny application for CI

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build my first R Shiny application. I want to build a confidence interval simulation, in which there are sliders at the side, and when you change something (sample size, confidence level, standard deviation or mean), a plot of the confidence interval length changes in reaction. I have taken a sliders example from the Shiny website, and tried changing, it doesn't work. After some minor changes I get the message "Error in tag("form", list(...)) : argument is missing, with no default". In addition, I do not know how to make a nice plot of the confidence interval, with the mean in the middle, can you assist please ?
My current code is:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for slider demo application
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  #  Application title
  titlePanel("Confidence Interval for the mean when sigma is known"),

  # Sidebar with sliders that demonstrate various available
  # options
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # Simple integer interval
      sliderInput("mean", "Mean:", 
                  min=0, max=500, value=250),

      # Decimal interval with step value
      sliderInput("confidence", "Confidence level:", 
                  min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.95, step= 0.01),

      # Specification of range within an interval
      sliderInput("sigma", "Standard deviation:",
                  min = 0, max = 300, value = 10),

      # Provide a custom currency format for value display, 
      # with basic animation
      sliderInput("Samplesize", "Sample size:", 
                  min = 0, max = 1000, value = 30, step = 1),

      ),

    # Show a table summarizing the values entered
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("values")
    )
  )
))
```

and

```
library(shiny)

# Define server logic for slider examples
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Reactive expression to compose a data frame containing all of
  # the values
  sliderValues <- reactive({

    # Compose data frame
    data.frame(
      Name = c("Mean", 
               "Confidence Interval",
               "Standard Deviation",
               "Sample size"),
      Value = as.character(c(input$mean, 
                             input$confidence,
                             input$sigma,
                             input$samplesize), 
      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  }) 

  # Show the values using an HTML table
  output$values <- renderTable({
    sliderValues()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO, and congratulations for providing such a well documented example.

Shiny's error messages are crytpic to uncomprehensible because of the nested structure, and debugging can be nasty. There are a few "minor" errors in your code:

- The message comes from a comma after SliderInput("samplesize",...), where another expression is expected.
- In ui, there should be one more closing ")" after data.frame()
- "s(S)amplesize" is spelled inconsistently